Cant see container data in copied multisite
I converted my html,css,js site into wp site. At first i created all custom post types, carbon fields etc. in russian language. After i fully finished converting process and every text, image, and custom post was in wp_admin i needed to add new language to my site, english language. I used plugin Carbon Fields for custom fields.
I already solved that problem in another project, where i used ACF Pro for custom fields, lets say it is example.com. I setup wp multisite and just used NS Cloner, cloned my site and get new site.
Rus version site url:
example.com/…
Eng version site url
example.com/en/…
At eng version of example.com in wp admin in theme container i get same fields, same custom posts as at rus version, but empty and i just needed to fill them in english.
So i decided to use this method in current project. I added wp multisite support, cloned my russian version wia NS Cloner and instead of this (in section of menu where must be theme container)
Screenshot 1 - wordpress theme container in admin on russian language
At new eng version of site i got this
Screenshot 2 - wordpress theme container in admin on eng language
Looks like carbon fields created container, but does not show any fields of it.
If this will help to understand problem, i still can get values with carbon_get_theme_option() at /en/ version, but it returns data from russian version and, as i said, in wp admin i cant see fields where i can change them.
I installed carbon fields wia .zip, so, as i understood, i dont need to use ::boot() method.
My carbon fields require code in functions.php:
add_action('carbon_fields_register_fields', 'register_carbon_fields');
function register_carbon_fields()
{
    \Carbon_Fields\Carbon_Fields::boot();

    require_once __DIR__ . '/carbon_fields/custom-fields-options/theme-optons.php';
    require_once __DIR__ . '/carbon_fields/custom-fields-options/post-options.php';
    require_once __DIR__ . '/carbon_fields/custom-fields-options/term-options.php';
}

theme-optons.php:
<?php

if (!defined('ABSPATH')) {
    exit();
}

use Carbon_Fields\Container;
use Carbon_Fields\Field;

Container::make('post_meta', 'Информация о сырке')
    ->show_on_post_type('cheeses')
    ->set_priority('high')
    ->add_tab(
        'Главное',
        array(
            Field::make('text', 'cheese_name', 'Название'),
            Field::make('image', 'cheese_image', 'Картинка'),
            Field::make('checkbox', 'cheese_is_new', 'Новинка?')
        )
    )
    ->add_tab(
        'Подробная информация',
        array(
           .........

(post options and term options are looks the same).
My .htaccess
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]

My wp-config.php:
define('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true );
define( 'MULTISITE', true );
define( 'SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false );
define( 'DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'MY_SITE_URL.com' );
define( 'PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/' );
define( 'SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1 );
define( 'BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1 );

I tried searching but i just found https://community.carbonfields.net/t/multisite-switch-to-blog-to-get-field-values-not-working/514/2 this article. There topic holder said, that he needed to do_action(“carbon_fields_fields_registered”) and “carbon_fields_register_fields”. I tried to do this but this did not help.
Please help me understand where is the problem.
